# VS2010 Performance Profiler, Error VSP1363: Cross session profiling failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, visual-studio-2010

I’m running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1, Windows Vista Ultimate SP2, IIS 7.  IIS 7 has all the IIS 6 compatibility components installed.

I’m attempting to analyze performance with within a ASP.net/C# 4.0 web application using the Performance Wizard.  I launch the Performance Wizard, Select CPU Sampling, then my web project, then launch the profiler.  My application builds and once it starts to launch into the debugger I get an error dialog that says “Error VSP1363: Cross session profiling failed”.

I’ve checked the event viewer, there’s no errors in either the Application or System logs.

I’ve attempt the same operation against 2 different web projects with the same results.

I’ve attempted to launch the profiler with the “An ASP.NET or JavaScript application” option and entered the local url to IIS and open a separate browser to the application, I receive the same cross section error.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on VS 2010 perf tools some time ago. But keep retrying from time to time. Now running on W7x64 and IIS7 I was banging my head against this cross-session and VSP 7008: ASP.net exception: "" in VSPerfASPNETCmd.
So I'm back to JetBrains Trace Profiler and this is my answer :)! Works perfectly under all same conditions where VS tools fail.
If only MS used/tested their own profiling tools from time to time!